# Images being cut off Outlook 2007/2010/2013

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I am building a responsive HTML email template, and when I Litmus test my layout, the images are being cut off at the top, as shown below...

[image]

Any reason why this is? Here is some code, with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7UhGw/)

```
<table style="color: #4b4b4b; font-size:12px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 18px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; " >
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td height="40" width="40"><img src="http://www.uploadlibrary.com/TelecomsWorld/CALL-STATS/stats_07.jpg" width="40" height="40" style="display:block;" /></td>
<td>Geographic call mapping across the UK</td>
</tr>
...
```

I have researched, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201185/images-getting-cut-off-in-outlook-2007-2010) was found, but no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `line-height` (and possibly the `mso-line-height-rule`) set on the table is causing Outlook to push the image up.

Do you really need it? If not, I suggest removing it. If you need it either set it on the `<td>` that wraps the text or add another table to wrap just the text and set the line-height there.

**Update:** I edited your code snippet to reflect the actual code that is shown in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Add the same dimensions to the table cell that are already part of the image.

```
<td class="center" align="left" style="margin: 0;" height="32" width="540"><img src="http://www.uploadlibrary.com/TelecomsWorld/GENERAL/lowbluespeechedge.jpg" width="540" height="32" class="img_scale" style="display:block;" /></td>
```

Also:

> IS YOUR BUSINESS GROWING TO IT'S FULL POTENTIAL?

`It's` means `it is`. The possessive form of "it" has no apostrophe.

Comment: Hi there, tried the mentioned code, comes out the same though. Here is the Litmus test result... https://litmus.com/pub/ca7806d/screenshots